# Spring boot - Close connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, http

Is it possible for a spring endpoint to abruptly close connection ?

Ex :

```
  @GetMapping(/connectionClosedByPeerEndPoint)
  String foo(){
    //Close connection, and send no http response at all
  }
```

or simply to close connection abrupltly even before reaching the endpoint, like mid http handshake(without FIN signal ?). What conf one would one need to do in order to achieve that.

The purpose of this is nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add to application.properties

```
server.shutdown=graceful
```

or that one:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i'm not trying to shutdown the server. I want to close the httpconnexion midway trough a request so that the client generate something like a connectionClosedByPeerException (I think that's how netty calls it)

Answer (score 0):

You should create `ConfigurableApplicationContext` in main class and create method that closes it, e.g.:

```
public class SpringBootApplication {
    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static void finish(){
        context.close();
    }

}
```

And your code in controller should be next:

```
@GetMapping("/exit")
    public void exit(){
        SpringBootApplication.finish();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i'm not trying to shutdown the server. I want to close the httpconnexion midway trough a request so that the client generate something like a connectionClosedByPeerException (I think that's how netty calls it)